# Copy from all rows one Worksheet and paste in to Another in alternate rows(Excel vba)

Tags: excel, vba

I have to copy rows from Worksheet A to Worksheet B. However, I have to paste in alternate rows like:

```
1 st row(Sheet A)-- 1 st row (Sheet B)
2nd row (Sheet A) --> 3rd row (Sheet B)
3rd row (Sheet A)--> 5th row(Sheet B)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set dws = Sheets("Sheet2")
lr = sws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
dws.Cells.Clear
sws.UsedRange.Copy dws.Range("A1")
For i = lr To 1 Step -1
    dws.Rows(i).Insert
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Edited Answer:**

You may try this approach which will be faster enough to copy the data from Sheet1 into Sheet2. The only downside is it will copy the values only not the formulas if any on Sheet1.

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, ii As Long, j As Long
Dim x, y()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set dws = Sheets("Sheet2")
dws.Cells.Clear
x = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim y(1 To UBound(x, 1) * 2, 1 To UBound(x, 2))
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    j = j + 2
    For ii = 1 To UBound(x, 2)
        y(j, ii) = x(i, ii)
    Next ii
Next i
dws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(y, 1), UBound(y, 2)).Value = y
End Sub
```

Comment: What did not work? Were you able to understand the code so that you could tweak it if required. The code is pretty simple. It copies all the data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 and then insert a row in between on Sheet2. Or on Sheet2 you already have some data in even rows which you don't want to replace with Sheet1 data?

Comment: hello,it does sound like exactly what i need.However when i run this code it seems to go into an endless loop-doesnt give an error doesnot get the sheet updated either and the excel sheet becomes"not responding".Is there any reason for this

Comment: I guess its because of the range of data used,i reduced the rows to 5 and it worked!.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any way this code can be used for a large amount of data say 100's of rows

Comment: How many rows and columns of data you have on Sheet1? Are there any formulas on Sheet1?

Comment: I have added another answer. See if that works faster with the amount of data you have on Sheet1.

Comment: @Sona123 Glad it worked as desired. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.